# Running SDL app via RealVNC with Direct Capture enabled does not accept Keyboard input

Tags: vnc, keyboard, sdl

I am trying to run and SDL hardware-accelerated app, PICO,-8 over VNC, and thanks to this community I am making progress!

One solution is to use RealVNC with the experimental DirectCapture feature enabled. When I do this, PICO-8 launches, but the app does not respond to keyboard commands at all.

How can I send keyboard commands to PICO-8 when using the DirectCapture feature?

Answer (score 1):

If you can run PICO-8 without X11 then this may work, since the RealVNC server uses a different method to inject input events (uinput) when X11 isn't running.

Comment: I believe there is a direct framebuffer support baked in... Would setting the sdl_videodriber envar be sufficient to force the app away from x11?